# How to model the marginals of a copula as student t distributions in R

Tags: r

I am trying to model the performance of a portfolio consisting of a basket of ETFs. To do this, I am using a T copula. For now, I have specified the marginals (i.e. the performance of the individual ETFs) as being normal, however, I want to use a Student t-distribution instead of a normal distribution.

I have looked into the `fit.st()` method from the QRM package, but I am unsure how to combine this with the `copula` package.

I know how to implement normally distributed margins:

```
mv.NE <- mvdc(normalCopula(0.75), c("norm"),
              list(list(mean = 0, sd =2)))
```

How can I do the same thing, but with a t-distribution?

Comment: Just replace normal copula with t copula.

Answer (score 0):

All that you need to do is to use `tCopula` instead of the `normalCopula`. You need to set up the parameter and degree of freedom of t-copula. And you need to specify the margins as well.

Hence, here we replace the `normalCopula` with `tCopula` and `df=5` is the degree of freedom. Both margins are normal (as you want).

`mv.NE <- mvdc(tCopula(0.75, df=5), c("norm", "norm"),
+               list(list(mean = 0, sd =2), list(list(mean = 0, sd =2))))`

The result is:

```
 Multivariate Distribution Copula based ("mvdc")
 @ copula:
t-copula, dim. d = 2 
Dimension:  2 
Parameters:
  rho.1   = 0.75
  df      = 5.00
 @ margins:
[1] "norm" "norm"
   with 2 (not identical)  margins; with parameters (@ paramMargins) 
List of 2
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ mean: num 0
  ..$ sd  : num 2
 $ :List of 1
  ..$ mean:List of 2
  .. ..$ mean: num 0
  .. ..$ sd  : num 2
```

For `t-margins`, use this:

`mv.NE <- mvdc(tCopula(0.75), c("t","t"),list(t=5,t=5))`

```
Multivariate Distribution Copula based ("mvdc")
 @ copula:
t-copula, dim. d = 2 
Dimension:  2 
Parameters:
  rho.1   = 0.75
  df      = 4.00
 @ margins:
[1] "t" "t"
   with 2 (not identical)  margins; with parameters (@ paramMargins) 
List of 2
 $ t: Named num 5
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "df"
 $ t: Named num 5
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "df"
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to model the marginals with a t-distribution?

Comment: It is based on your data. Use Voung test to compare the two models and see which one is the best for your data. Margins are almost unknown in the practice. If you fit wrong margins then this will affect the estimation of the copula and hence end up with an inaccurate result.

Comment: Sure ... But how will I go about modelling the marginals as following a t-distribution?